# Suggested edits count badge shouldn't be displayed in top bar after reaching daily quota

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

[image]

There's a badge in the top bar showing the number of suggested edits that need to be reviewed, which is nice. However, once I've reviewed 20 and can't review any more, that badge is still displayed.

Why show me a call to action if I'm not able to review any more edits today?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes

Comment: Not only that, but the mouseover tooltip tells you that the number is "**total posts awaiting review**", and that display is not removed when all review queues have **zero** posts awaiting review.

Comment: It turns out if you fail an audit, resulting in a review ban, this icon keeps showing up even when you are currently locked out of *all* review queues.